# Android - Center Grid View in Linear Layout AND use Horizontal Spacing

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have an Android app in which I am trying to center a grid view in a linear layout.  I don't have to use the linear layout, but I prefer to if possible.

I want to set the horizontal spacing (space between columns) in the grid view, as well as center the grid view in the parent.

When I use `android:stretchMode="none"` in the XML, the horizontal spacing works.  However when I do this the grid view is left aligned.  Using `android:stretchMode="columnWidth"` the grid view is centered, but the horizontal spacing does not work.

How can I have both?

Sample of my XML below (horizontal spacing works, centering does not):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/myList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"

        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:columnWidth="400dp"

        android:stretchMode="none"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    </GridView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center a component as GridView, the best way is to use RelativeLayout.
You could use layout_centerInParent to center both horizontal & vertical or layout_centerHorizontal to center horizontal only.

For instance:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <GridView
        [...]
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @DJElbow Is it useful ? or you need more info ?

Comment: This works until I add `android:horizontalSpacing="1dp", android:columnWidth="400dp", and android:stretchMode="none"`.  Same problem I am having with the linear layout.  The grid view actually centers correctly with the linear layout also until I add these.

Comment: How many columns do you need ? if it's 2, you could set the width of gridlayout to 802dp (columnWidth + horizontalSpacing x2) and it's center GridView

Comment: Well, I would like to use the `auto_fit` if possible.  If I can't figure that out then I might have to set a width on the layout.